# Call Oracle Stored Procedure with Parameter from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, plsql, parameters

I need to call a stored procedure from Excel. The parameter is set in cell A1 (Date - 06.04.2022).

Below code is not working error message - "type mismatch"

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
 
 
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
 
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=" & _
                    "xxx" & _
                    "xxx" & _
                    "xxx" & _
                    "xxx;"
cn.Open
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "begin proc_name ('" + Range("A1") + "') ;"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandTimeout = 20
cmd.Execute
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
```

Stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure proc_name (prm_dt date)
```

Help solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you get the error on this line`"begin proc_name ('" + Range("A1") + "') ;"`? `+` is not the string concatenate operator, it's `&`. Try `"begin proc_name ('" & Range("A1") & "') ;"`. `+` might work in some case, but only if all the parameters are Strings, so it will work if A1 content is "text" but not if content is "1" or a date in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the `Date` value and wrong syntax.

Try this one:

```
cmd.CommandText = "begin proc_name (TO_DATE('" & Format(Range("A1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "','YYYY-MM-DD')) ; END; "
```

Or even better try prepared statements with bind parameter, like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "begin proc_name(?); END;"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("prm_dt", adDate, adParamInput, , Range("A1").Value)
```

Or try this syntax: `cmd.CommandText = "{CALL proc_name(?)}"`